# How to handle the "Select a certificate" windows pop-up with for chrome selenium webdriver with python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to get an url using webriver from selenium.

The url requires a certificate generated by my company and needs to be installed manually.

The problem is that I can't find a way to confirm the certificate using selenium webdriver, but also the fact that the code hangs up on `driver.get(URL)` and can no longer execute any further lines of code.
The pop up is not an element of the browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get (URL)
```

I can't share the URL because it's confidential.

**EDIT**

I managed to workaround this by loading creating a profile of the browser that has the certificate installed.
Then I just need to load the profile and continue working.

Answer (score 1):

Use [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) library to handle popup window. You can pass keyboard keys and handle the popup.